# variable USB3 / bluetooth interference with an MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, bluetooth

I've got: a hengedock, a late 2013 retina MBP, a USB3 hub, and a USB3 backup disk, and a bluetooth trackpad. Sometimes, it all works great. Sometimes, the pad goes on strike. At worst, it even disconnects. The situation got a little better when I maximized the distance from the mbp to the hub and disk, but it's still unpredictable. What could cause the fluctuations?

Comment: By 'on strike', do you mean the pad stops working (like when workers go on strike for more pay)?  What are the makes and models of hub, disk, and trackpad?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.